# How to do a regexp_replace for a single hiphen character?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I would like to replace hiphens in a column with 2 hiphens. I want to do this only if hiphen occurs by itself. For example

1. `'-'` should become `'--'`
2. `'a-b'` should remain as `'a-b'`
3. `'a - b'` should become `a -- b`
4. `'a -'` should become `a --`
5. `'- b'` should become `-- b`

What I have tried so far is `select regexp_replace(column, '[[:<:]]\-[[:>:]]', '--', 'gi')`. This is not working since the `'a-b'` becomes `'a--b'`

How should I proceed?

Comment: I wonder if `select regexp_replace(column, '[[:<:]](-)[[:>:]]|(-)', '\1\2\2', 'g')` works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex: [`( |^)-( |$)`](https://regex101.com/r/Tyh6nC/3) and replace with `\1--\2`

```
select regexp_replace(column, '( |^)-( |$)', '\1--\2', 'g')
```